JWT Authentication Fails with "No Authorization Header" for Protected Route in Node.js/Express App
I’m working on a Node.js/Express project that involves a login system using JWT for authentication. The user logs in through a login.html page, and upon successful login, I store the JWT token in localStorage. When trying to access a protected /adopt route, I get an error: {"error": "No authorization header"}.
I'm attempting to authenticate the user by sending the JWT token in the Authorization header for the /adopt page, but it seems like the token is not being recognized.
// adopt.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Adopt Page Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="debugInfo"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Loading adoption page...</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
        function appendDebug(message) {
            const debugDiv = document.getElementById('debugInfo');
            debugDiv.innerHTML += `<p>${message}</p>`;
        }
    
        async function checkAuthentication() {
            const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
            appendDebug(`Token in localStorage: ${token ? 'Found' : 'Not found'}`);
    
            if (!token) {
                appendDebug('No token found - redirecting to login');
                window.location.href = "/login";
                return;
            }
    
            try {
                appendDebug('Attempting to verify authentication...');
                const response = await fetch('/adopt', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,  // Set Bearer token
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });
    
                appendDebug(`Server response status: ${response.status}`);
    
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    appendDebug('Authentication failed - redirecting to login');
                    localStorage.removeItem('token'); // Clear invalid token
                    window.location.href = "/login";
                    return;
                }
    
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
                }
    
                appendDebug('Authentication successful!');
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = `
                    <h1>Welcome to the adopt pet page</h1>
                    <p>You are successfully authenticated!</p>
                `;
            } catch (error) {
                appendDebug(`Error: ${error.message}`);
                console.error('Authentication error:', error);
            }
        }
    
        // Run the authentication check when the page loads
        checkAuthentication();
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>


// login.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login to Adopt Pets</h1>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <input type="text" id="usernameOrEmail" placeholder="Username or Email" required />
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
        const messageDiv = document.getElementById('message');

        form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            const usernameOrEmail = document.getElementById('usernameOrEmail').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;

            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        usernameOrEmail,  // Sending single field to backend
                        password
                    })
                });

                const result = await response.json();

                if (response.ok) {
                    // Store the token in localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem('token', result.token);

                    // Clear form fields after successful login
                    form.reset();

                    // Redirect to the adopt page
                    window.location.href = '/adopt';
                } else {
                    messageDiv.innerHTML = result.msg || 'Login failed';
                }
            } catch (error) {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>


// index.js 
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

const jwtSecret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const user = require("./userData");

function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
    if (!authHeader) return res.status(401).json({ error: "No authorization header" });

    const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ error: "No token provided" });

    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.status(403).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
}

// Login endpoint
app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
    const { usernameOrEmail, password } = req.body;
    const user = userExists(usernameOrEmail, usernameOrEmail);
    if (!user) return res.status(403).json({ msg: "User does not exist" });

    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!passwordMatch) return res.status(403).json({ msg: "Invalid credentials" });

    const token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, email: user.email }, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: "1h" });
    res.status(200).json({ token });
});

// Protected adopt route
app.get("/adopt", authenticateToken, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/adopt.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running on port 3000"));


Token in Local Storage:
After login, the JWT token is correctly stored in localStorage. When I log the token in adopt.html, it shows up as expected.
Authorization Header:
I'm sending the token in the Authorization header (Bearer ), but the server logs show it as undefined and returns a "No authorization header" error.
CORS Setup:
I configured CORS on the server, allowing Authorization and Content-Type headers, but the issue persists.
What I'm Expecting:
The server should receive the Authorization header correctly, verify the JWT token, and allow access to the /adopt route if valid.

solved the problem using cookie , but still don't know how to do with Local Storage in which we have to put token manually to route where we want the token
